# Return a sum of a column based on multiple criteria, SUMIFS usage?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to result in the sum of E4:E22 after validating that N4:N22's values' months and years match the values in B2 and A2. If both return true, add the value in E to the total sum.

I appreciate the help!

I've tried formulas such as SUMIF `=(SUMIF($E$4:$E, $N$4:$N, TEXT(N4, "MMM") = B2, $N$4:$N, TEXT(N4, "YYYY"))` and various other options, but I think I may be approaching this wrong.

Comment: FYI posting an _image_ of data makes it harder for people to help you. Always post a plan text (formated) version of the data (edit it into your Q).  If you think am image adds context, you can always add that as well.

Comment: Is it as simple as adding an ` = A2` for the year?  (`=(SUMIF($E$4:$E, $N$4:$N, TEXT(N4, "MMM") = B2, $N$4:$N, TEXT(N4, "YYYY") = A2)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIFS` and `SUMIF` both work well if you don't have to modify the values in your criteria columns, but aren't always ideal in situations where you want to compare against transformed values of one or more columns.

Instead, this is a good fit for `FILTER`, `SUM`, and `IFERROR`:

1. Use `FILTER` to select the values you want to add.
2. Use regular old `SUM` to add them up.
3. Wrap in an `IFERROR` to default to 0 when no matches are returned by `FILTER`.

Another issue I noticed was that you were trying to compare a *string* year value returned by `TEXT` to the *integer* year value in `$A$2`. You could solve this by wrapping `TEXT` in `INT` to cast the string into an integer (i.e. `INT(TEXT($N$4:$N, "YYYY"))`), but I opted to use `YEAR` (i.e. `YEAR($N$4:$N)`) instead because it's a bit cleaner.

Give this a shot:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($E$4:$E, TEXT($N$4:$N, "MMM")=$B$2, YEAR($N$4:$N)=$A$2)), 0)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, and thank you for the information. Thank you very much!